# ARC vs. non-ARC removeLastObject method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to learn from the iTunes U iPhone programming lectures.

There is a question that I have in regards to the following method code:

```
+(double) popOperandOffStack:(NSMutableArray *) stack{
    double result = 0;

    id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
    if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject];

    if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
        result = [topOfStack doubleValue];
    }
    else if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){

        if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"+"]){
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] + [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }

        if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"-"]){
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] - [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }

        if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"*"]){
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] * [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }

        if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"/"]){
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] / [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }


    }

    return result;
}
```

How is topOfStack still accessible even though removeLastObject has already been called on it. In the past, removeLastObject would send a release to the removed object, so how is topOfStack still valid? I'm guessing that this is something ARC-related, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

All variables have a strong reference by default under ARC. While the stack may lose its reference to the last object, the variable topOfStack still refers to it and therefore the value of topOfStack is not deleted from memory.

Answer (score 1):

In ARC all local variables without qualifiers are assumed to be `__strong` references. This means `topOfStack` is a strong reference to what was the last object of `stack`. Thus it retains it even thought the object is released by the array when it is removed. So `topOfStack` will continue to be valid until it goes out of scope when ARC will release it automatically.